# Extract numbers from filename

Tags: bash, sed

In BASH I thought to use `sed`, but can't figure how to extract pattern instead usual replace.

For example:

FILENAME = 'blah_blah_#######_blah.ext'

number of ciphers (in above example written with "#" substitute) could be either 7 or 10

I want to extract only the number

Comment: Do you want to extract the number of ciphers (digits?)? Or the number which the ciphers represent? It would also be helpful if you just posted a couple of examples to run the query against.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

If all you need is to remove anything but digits, you could use

```
ls | sed -e s/[^0-9]//g
```

to get all digits grouped per filename (123test456.ext will become 123456), or

```
ls | egrep -o [0-9]+
```

for all groups of numbers (123test456.ext will turn up 123 and 456)

Comment: wont work if there is number anywhere in filename. I need only 7 or 10 digit extract. Perhaps I could use {} but I'm not very familiar with sed

Comment: Then add a quantifier, like `ls | egrep -o '[0-9]{7,10}'` (this is slightly border line, will match strings of digits between seven and ten characters long).

Comment: Yes, that's the way to go. `sed` perhaps does not accept {} repeaters. Thanks

Comment: As for border case: `ls | egrep -o '[0-9]{10}|[0-9]{7}'`

Answer (score 11):

You can use this simple code:

```
filename=zc_adsf_qwer132467_xcvasdfrqw
echo ${filename//[^0-9]/}   # ==> 132467
```

Comment: now combine with array element `echo ${${array[-2]}//[^0-9]/}` -> bad substitution

Answer (score 6):

Just bash:

```
shopt -s extglob
filename=zc_adsf_qwer132467_xcvasdfrqw
tmp=${filename##+([^0-9])}
nums=${tmp%%+([^0-9])}
echo $nums   # ==> 132467
```

or, with bash 4

```
[[ "$filename" =~ [0-9]+ ]] && nums=${BASH_REMATCH[0]}
```

Answer (score 2):

Is there any number anywhere else in the file name? If not:

```
 ls | sed 's/[^0-9][^0-9]*\([0-9][0-9]*\).*/\1/g'
```

Should work.

A Perl one liner might work a bit better because Perl simply has a more advanced regular expression parsing and will give you the ability to specify the range of digits must be between 7 and 10:

```
ls | perl -ne 's/.*\D+(\d{7,10}).*/$1/;print if /^\d+$/;'
```

Answer (score 1):

```
$ ls -1
blah_blah_123_blah.ext
blah_blah_234_blah.ext
blah_blah_456_blah.ext
```

Having such files in a directory you run:

```
$ ls -1 | sed 's/blah_blah_//' | sed 's/_blah.ext//'
123
234
456
```

or with a single `sed` run:

```
$ ls -1 | sed 's/^blah_blah_\([0-9]*\)_blah.ext$/\1/'
```

Comment: double replace. ok, but 'blah_blah..' is not real name of course. how can you know were number starts

Answer (score 0):

This will work for you -

```
echo $FILENAME | sed -e 's/[^(0-9|)]//g' | sed -e 's/|/,/g'
```